# How to increase space width of text using css on condition of language used?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, fonts

I am using "Nafees Nastaliq" font on a wordpress website. This font provides English and Urdu characters to write in both languages. Urdu language doesn't need that width of space that english language needs. So, the font contains a narrow width of "space" character. On the website, I have to type English and Urdu both sometimes in the same div. So, is their anyway to increase the width of "space" character only when their is a space character between two characters which are both in English? Here is an example screenshot, how it look likes:

[image: See Image]

In the above example, system should check that if their is English words like "No Categories", so the space between "no" and "Categories" should be maximized in width just like it should be in English. But for the urdu side "اصنافِ سخن" it should not increase the width of space.

Here is CSS:

```
li {
    font-family: 'Nafees Nastaliq' !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Pseduo Code I have : But how to implement?

1. Select a "space"
2. check if left side character is in (A,B,C.. a,b,c...) AND check if right side character is in (A,B,C.. a,b,c...)
3. If yes, then increase_space_width()

   4. else use_space_as_it_is() or do_nothing();

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I think that's not possible with CSS.  there's no way for the CSS to know what language the character is in.  Best bet is to either use two fonts, one for each language, or _maybe_ there's a single font that does what you want, but I'm not aware of anything like that

Comment: Are you using the HTLM element `lang` attribute, and the corresponding `:lang(...)` CSS pseudo-selector?

Comment: no what is that? will lang(...) help in this?

Answer (score 1):

Put all your characters or words that you want to write in Urdu language, in a span with a specific class name. For example:

HTML CODE:

```
<p>
    This paragraph contains multiple languages such as Englsih and <span class="urdu">اردو</span> at the same time. 
</p>
```

CSS CODE:

```
p {
    font-familly: "English Font", "Urdu Font";
    font-weight: bBold;
}
p .urdu {
    font-weight: normal;
    /* Your custome style for Urdu language only */
}
```